# Configure IIS for internal c# web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, iis-8

I have a number of C# web applications that I have deployed to our in house web server so they can be available only to our internal users.

The webserver is running IIS 8.5 and I have set up a couple of sites in this that point at the applications, this is working fine except that the url you have to use to navigate to the applications is in the following format `serverName:portNumber`.

I would like to change this so the urls are more user friendly and they dont have to remember the server name and the port number.

I am an IIS noob so I don't know what to look into/try so any explanation using words of one syllable would be greatly appreciated!

I have seen that this might involve something to do with bindings (?) so I have included my current binding settings for my sites below.

```
Site1
Name: MySite1
Type: http
Host name: null
Port: 80
IP Address: *
Binding Information: null
Desired URL: www.mysite1.com or something equivalent

Site2
Name: MySite2
Type: http
Host name: null
Port: 81
IP Address: *
Binding Information: null
Desired URL: www.mysite2.com or something equivalent
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: this belongs on [sf]

Answer (score 0):

In IIS you can right click on each website and go to Edit Bindings and you will be able to configure IP addresses and ports in there. If you leave the IP address as * (or "All Unassigned" as IIS calls it) and you want to have multiple sites with the same port number (80), then you need to specify the host name for each site. www.mysite1.com for the first site and www.mysite2.com for the second site as in your example. Of course you'll have to make sure those host names are in DNS so that your users will be able to connect to the server when they type in the URL.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing bindings from `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

There will be a line '127.0.0.1  localhost' which you can uncomment and add your ip's here.
eg : `ip : port staging.yoursite.com`

Comment: The hosts file doesn't deal with ports.